# How to disable orientation changes for main activity?

Tags: android

I have a relativelayout with a scrollview like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="576dp"
 android:background="@drawable/text_main" 
 >
```

I want to stop the orientation changes and make it fixed vertical. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the **MainActivity** in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
...
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
... >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

under your

```
 <activity>
```

tag in your manifest you can put

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this

1. **Static**

   ```
       <activity
           android:name="com.photon.filnobep.activities.ActivitySettings"
           android:icon="@drawable/icon_small"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_settings"
           android:logo="@drawable/icon_small"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
       </activity>
   ```
2. **Pro-grammatically(In your java class)**

   **setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);**

---

**Note:** using Static method you still can change Orientation from you java Class